# How to delete a folder in my local using javascript

Tags: javascript, mobile-application

I want to delete an empty/non-empty directory from my local system and i have restriction that i need to do that only using javascript functions.I cannot refer to functions like 'FileSystemObject'
Please help!

**Please Note:**
I need solution for above issue as I am working on mobile app which support javascript only

Comment: use node js and its addon fs for that

Comment: Hi Alexander,
Thanks for quick reply.Can you please share any sample code for that.
As i tried to search all alternates to delete folder but was not able to do that.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rmdir_path_callback

Answer (score 0):

This function should work. Removes files synchronously
Pass `removeself = true` to remove the empty directory.

```
 const path = require('path');
 const fs = require('fs');
 const rmDir = function (dirPath, removeSelf) {
  if (removeSelf === undefined)
    removeSelf = true;
  try {
    var files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath);
  } catch (e) {
    // throw e
    return;
  }
  if (files.length > 0)
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      const filePath = path.join(dirPath, files[i]);
      if (fs.statSync(filePath).isFile())
        fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
      else
        rmDir(filePath);
    }
  if (removeSelf)
    fs.rmdirSync(dirPath);
};
```

Disclaimer: Not my code, copied from someone's gist(forgot the url).

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for sharing code..i will try to implement the same:)

Comment: oops, didn't read your question properly. Not sure this is will run in mobile, I thought question is about server side, sorry